# The type in global.d.ts file can't be used in another tsx file with typescirpt?

Tags: typescript

I have a `global.d.ts` file with code below:

```js
enum StatusCode {
  SUCCESS = 0,
  FAIL = 1
}
```

and I wanna use the type declared in `global.d.ts` in another file, such as `index.tsx`:

```js
const status: StatusCode = 0; // This is no problem at all
```

but I got an `ReferenceError` said `Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): StatusCode is not defined` when code like this in `index.tsx`:

```js
let code = ...;
if (code === StatusCode.SUCCESS) {
  // ...
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
```

Can someone explain to me why this is so? Thanks a lot.